# Getting 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string' Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the following query where I want to return a column with a date in the first instance, but not in the additional instances.  If you look at my query below, you can see that I am using a Union All to link the three similar queries I am running in MSS.  I am able to run each of these independently with no problems, but when I attempt to run them all together I get the error.  I apologize if this has been answered before, but I was wondering if someone can tell me what it is I am missing that will get me past this error.

I am fairly new to query writing and complex queries sometimes get the best of me. Thank you, in advance, for any help anyone can provide.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 
       b.[corp]
      ,c.[acctCorp]
      ,b.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[xrf_house_fgn_id]
      ,a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id]
      ,b.[house_only]
      ,a.[is_current_subscriber]
      ,a.[is_active_subscriber]
      ,('--') as DDPF_InstallDate
      ,('--') as DDP_IDATE
      ,('--') as DDPF_DiscChangeToDate
      ,('--') as DDP_BDATE
      ,[merge_date] as Conversion_Date
      ,d.[hse_status_date]
      ,e.[hse_drop_status_date]
      ,f.[hse_lob_serv_stat_date]

  FROM 
            [amdocs7_6].[xrf_house] as b
  left join [amdocs7_6].[xrf_subscriber] as a on b.[corp] = a.[corp] and b.[ccs_id] = a.[xrf_house_ccs_id] 
  left join [site].[CorpGroup] as c on b.[corp] = c.[corpid] and c.[wave] = 1
  left join [trn].[hse_base] as d on b.[corp] = d.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = d.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_drop] as e on b.[corp] = e.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = e.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_lob] as f on b.[corp] = f.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = f.[hse_record_key] and f.[hse_lob_indicator] = 'C'
  left join [amdocs_XP].[Pay80Star] as g on a.[corp] = g.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = g.[Dwelling] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = g.[Customer]
  left join [amdocs7_6].[CF000T] as h on b.[corp] = h.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = h.[House] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = h.[Cust]
           ,[site].[spc_site_dates]

  WHERE
       b.[house_only] = 'Y'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT TOP 1000 
       b.[corp]
      ,c.[acctCorp]
      ,b.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[xrf_house_fgn_id]
      ,a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id]
      ,b.[house_only]
      ,a.[is_current_subscriber]
      ,a.[is_active_subscriber]
      ,('--') as DDPF_InstallDate
      ,('--') as DDP_IDATE
      ,CAST(g.[DiscChangeToDate] as Date) as DDPF_DiscChangeToDate
      ,CAST(h.[BDATE] as Date) as DDP_BDATE
      ,('--') as Conversion_Date
      ,d.[hse_status_date]
      ,e.[hse_drop_status_date]
      ,f.[hse_lob_serv_stat_date]

  FROM 
            [amdocs7_6].[xrf_house] as b
  left join [amdocs7_6].[xrf_subscriber] as a on b.[corp] = a.[corp] and b.[ccs_id] = a.[xrf_house_ccs_id] 
  left join [site].[CorpGroup] as c on b.[corp] = c.[corpid] and c.[wave] = 1
  left join [trn].[hse_base] as d on b.[corp] = d.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = d.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_drop] as e on b.[corp] = e.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = e.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_lob] as f on b.[corp] = f.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = f.[hse_record_key] and f.[hse_lob_indicator] = 'C'
  left join [amdocs_XP].[Pay80Star] as g on a.[corp] = g.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = g.[Dwelling] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = g.[Customer]
  left join [amdocs7_6].[CF000T] as h on b.[corp] = h.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = h.[House] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = h.[Cust]
           ,[site].[spc_site_dates]

  WHERE
       b.[house_only] = 'N'
   and a.[is_current_subscriber] = 'Y'
   and a.[is_active_subscriber] = 'N'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT TOP 1000 
       b.[corp]
      ,c.[acctCorp]
      ,b.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[ccs_id]
      ,a.[xrf_house_fgn_id]
      ,a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id]
      ,b.[house_only]
      ,a.[is_current_subscriber]
      ,a.[is_active_subscriber]
      ,CAST(g.[InstallDate] as Date) as DDPF_InstallDate
      ,CAST(h.[IDATE] as Date) as DDP_IDATE
      ,('--') as DDPF_DiscChangeToDate
      ,('--') as DDP_BDATE
      ,('--') as Conversion_Date
      ,d.[hse_status_date]
      ,e.[hse_drop_status_date]
      ,f.[hse_lob_serv_stat_date]

  FROM 
            [amdocs7_6].[xrf_house] as b
  left join [amdocs7_6].[xrf_subscriber] as a on b.[corp] = a.[corp] and b.[ccs_id] = a.[xrf_house_ccs_id] 
  left join [site].[CorpGroup] as c on b.[corp] = c.[corpid] and c.[wave] = 1
  left join [trn].[hse_base] as d on b.[corp] = d.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = d.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_drop] as e on b.[corp] = e.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = e.[hse_record_key]
  left join [trn].[hse_lob] as f on b.[corp] = f.[prtnId] and b.[ccs_id] = f.[hse_record_key] and f.[hse_lob_indicator] = 'C'
  left join [amdocs_XP].[Pay80Star] as g on a.[corp] = g.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = g.[Dwelling] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = g.[Customer]
  left join [amdocs7_6].[CF000T] as h on b.[corp] = h.[CORP] and a.[xrf_house_fgn_id] = h.[House] and a.[xrf_customer_fgn_id] = h.[Cust]
           ,[site].[spc_site_dates]

  WHERE
       b.[house_only] = 'N'
   and a.[is_current_subscriber] = 'Y'
   and a.[is_active_subscriber] = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data types of the columns returned from each query are different. A [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180026.aspx) query will take the data types from the various parts and try to implictly convert them to match. From the docs:

> The definitions of the columns that are part of a UNION operation do not have to be the same, but they must be compatible through implicit conversion. When data types differ, the resulting data type is determined based on the rules for data type precedence.

Here your first query has a `DATETIME` type in one of the columns but the second and/or third parts are presenting text data in that same column position.

It's impossible to tell without knowing exactly which column is the problem as we don't have the table sructures, but a good guess is the `Conversion_Date` column which looks like it could be a date in part 1 but is `--` in part 2 and 3. As `DATETIME` has a much higher precedence than `VARCHAR`, the query engine tries to convert that to a `DATETIME` value and fails.

Comment: Actually all of the columns with 'Date' in the name have a date part.  Is there a way to do what I am asking the way I have it written?

Comment: Instead of `--`, can you use `NULL`?